# Quicksort C - Segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, quicksort

I made a single Linked list. Now I want to make a quicksort but I'm getting segmentation fault and can't find where the problem is.

```
Invalid read of size 8
   at 0x400659: quicksort (liiista.c:23)   
   by 0x4008FE: main (liiista.c:117)
   Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Line 23 is the following:

```
while( (strcmp(arr[left]->ele,arr[pivot]->ele) <= 0) && left < end)
```

I post the code of the insert, main, and the quicksort function.

```
typedef struct celda{
  char* ele;
  struct celda *next;
}*tList;


void quicksort(tLista *arr, int begin, int end){
  char* temp;
  int left, right, pivot;

  if(begin < end){

    pivot = begin;
    left = begin;
    right = end;


    while(left < right){
        while( (strcmp(arr[left]->ele,arr[pivot]->ele) <= 0) && left < end) {
            left++;
        }   
        while( (strcmp( arr[right]->ele, arr[pivot]->ele) > 0)){
            right--;        
        }
        if(left<right){
            temp = arr[left]->ele;
            arr[left]->ele = arr[right]->ele;
            arr[right]->ele = temp;
        }                       
    }

    temp = arr[pivot]->ele;
    arr[pivot]->ele = arr[right]->ele;
    arr[right]->ele = temp;

    quicksort(&(*arr),begin,right-1);
    quicksort(&(*arr),left+1, end);

  } 
}

void insert(tList *myList, char* ele){

  tList node = (tList)malloc(sizeof(struct celda));
  node->ele = ele;
  node->next = *myList;
  *myList = node;

}


int main(){

  tList myList = NULL;
  insert(&myList,"a");
  insert(&myList,"b");
  insert(&myList,"c");
  insert(&myList,"d");
  insert(&myList,"e");

  quicksort(&myList,0,4);

  return 1;
}
```

I have try to find the mistake but I couldn't.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would be a good time to learn how to run your program using the debugger.  This should let you see exactly where your program is crashing, and inspect relevant variable values, which should help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @JimLewis Sorry, I forgot to put what the terminal shows. I edit the post.

Comment: what is the difference between `tLista` and `tList`?

Comment: @Wimmel Sorry i typo. I translate the spanish words to english and I forgot that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `quicksort` function, it expects to be passed an array of pointers to `struct celda`, however you're passing in the address of the address of the first node in a linked list.  You can't mix up data structures like that.

Comment: I am passing a pointer to a pointer that is pointing to the first node of the list. Then I am using array index to get the elements in the list. I mean:

   `tList *p = &myList;`
then
    `p[0]->ele  `
is the same as 
    `myList->ele`

Comment: That's not how it works.  When you create a linked list, the next node in the list can be anywhere in memory.  The elements are not laid out sequentially, so you have to traverse the list via the `next` pointer.